# IndexedDB UnknownError "A request was aborted, for example through a call to IDBTransaction.abort." occurs in Firefox OS app

Tags: indexeddb, firefox-os

When trying to insert more than 10000 records to IndexedDB in a Firefox OS app, I get an

> UnknownError "A request was aborted, for example through a call to IDBTransaction.abort."

I am trying to insert records to 3 different tables.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are hitting the storage limit of indexed db?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API#Storage_limits